# MvvmLight, Messenger, and Async method calls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, task-parallel-library, mvvm-light

I am using MvvmLight and have implemented communication between some of my ViewModels using the MessengerInstance.Send(...) method. It works great!

Recently, though, I have moved from using Synchronous methods to async methods to retrieve data and it looks like this breaks messaging (probably because it executes on a different thread). For example:

```
public ICommand SomeCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(DoSomething); } }

private async void DoSomething(object obj)
{
    //Used to be SomeWcfService.DoSomething(); with some logic afterward
    await SomeWcfService.DoSomethingAsync().ContinueWith(task => { //Some logic after method completes });

    MessengerInstance.Send(SomeDataToSend, MessageIdentifer.DoSomething);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a continuation, just put it after the await:

```
private async void DoSomething(object obj)
{
    //Used to be SomeWcfService.DoSomething(); with some logic afterward
    var result = await SomeWcfService.DoSomethingAsync();

    // .ContinueWith(task => { //Some logic after method completes });
    // use result here!

    MessengerInstance.Send(SomeDataToSend, MessageIdentifer.DoSomething);
}
```

If there is no result returned from `DoSomethingAsync`, you can just leave out the result, and put your code in place.

The continuation, as you wrote it, will not run on the same synchronization context.  The `await` keyword is actually asynchronously waiting your continuation, not the async method from WCF, as well.

If your "some logic" is asynchronous, you can use `await` within that code, as well.

Comment: I was thinking the MessengerInstance.Send() was not running in the same thread because `DoSomething` (the class method, not the WCF) was running on a separate thread. This was making me think it was why my unit tests weren't seeing the message pop up. I don't know if that was the case, but doing what you suggested (not using the continuation) worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: `async void`? Shouldn't this be `async Task` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Typically it has to be a void method to use in most command implementations.  I have one that works with `async Task`, but most require `async void` (*unfortunately)`